# How to use this code to display all entries and compare?

Tags: php, validation

I have this code below that selects all id's for posts and then the snippet below that sees if there is a match.  If a match it says duplicate.  I tested it by using print command to print $test and print $unique but it only shows one id rather than all ids.  How can i fix this code so it will display all id # and then compare to see if a duplicate exists and if exists it will say "duplicate."

```
         $sql="SELECT `Post_id` from `posts`";  
         $result=mysql_query($sql);

         $query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

         if ($result == "")
         {
         echo "";
         }
         echo "";


         $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

         if($rows == 0)
         {
         print("");

         }
         elseif($rows > 0)
         {
         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
         {

         $storedid = htmlspecialchars($row['Note_id']);

         print("");
         }

         }

       //This $test id exists and $storedid should contain 
       3VRDY but it still goes through

       $test = "3VRDY";

      if ( $storedid == $test ) {
  echo("duplicate");
      die();
      } else {
  echo("");

      }
```

Comment: @Gerep not sure what you mean....

Comment: you are trying to retrieve a list of Note_id and check if there is any duplicate right? to do that, you need to check on a loop (while, for, foreach) this way you are going to check all the values returned from your database.

Comment: the `$test` value will no change? it will always have a fixed value?

Comment: no the $test valued i fixed so that i could see if my code will detect duplicate. I am not sure how to do a while for each to this code but let me look it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$test = '3VRDY';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
   $storedid = htmlspecialchars($row['Note_id']);
   if($storedid == $test)
        echo 'The ' . $storedid .' is duplicated<br/>';
   else
        echo 'The ' . $storedid .' is unique<br/>';
}
```

At the end of the loop you will have the results.

Comment: OK this works but instead of echoing all entries how can i just make the code detect it and use die(); if there is a duplicate? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, you can do that, inside the `if` where `$storedid == $test`, just replace the `echo` with `die()`

Comment: By the way are you a programmer for hire?

Comment: contact me daniel.gerep at gmail.com